# Geckolib3 - custom renderer for the player?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

i am relatively new to fabric and java as a whole, and i wanted to make a fabric mod which requires some custom animations for the player, but i have no idea how to implement them. My main objective is to make a custom renderer that the player will see from 3rd person, and can be easily switched to the old way minecraft renders the player. Any tips/ideas?

One idea i had is that i can make a custom entity that the player will ride and cant unmount, but this has its own issues, so i need other solutions

Comment: Much more effort goes into trying to understand stack**overflow** posts than into typing/editing them: Please correct capitalisation.